# pandas: tricking outerjoin

Tags: python, pandas

Im new using python

please how should i do to get the result below. if the cod and date match of df_1 exists in df_2 then i should add the row as explained in my code below.

```
data1 = {'date': ['2021-06', '2021-06', '2021-07', '2021-07', '2021-07', '2021-07'], 'cod': ['12', '12', '14', '15', '15', '18'], 'Zone': ['LA', 'NY', 'LA', 'NY', 'PARIS', 'PARIS'], 'Revenue_Radio': [10, 20, 30, 50, 40, 10]}  
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data1) 
data2 = {'date': ['2021-06', '2021-06', '2021-07', '2021-07', '2021-08'], 'cod': ['12', '14', '15', '15', '18'], 'Zone': ['PARIS', 'NY', 'LA', 'NY', 'NY'], 'Revenue_Str': [10, 20, 30, 50, 5]}  
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

My code id

```
dfx = df_2[df_2['cod'].isin(df_1['cod']) & 
(df_2['date'].isin(df_1['date'])) ]
df = (df_1.merge(dfx, on=['date','cod','Zone'], how='outer')
  .fillna(0)
  .sort_values(['date','cod'], ignore_index=True))
```

Expected output

```
data_result = {'date': ['2021-06', '2021-06', '2021-06', '2021-07', '2021-07', '2021-07', '2021-07', '2021-07','2021-07'], 'cod': ['12', '12', '12', '14', '14', '15', '15', '15', '18'], 'Zone': ['LA', 'NY', 'PARIS','LA', 'NY', 'NY', 'PARIS', 'LA', 'PARIS'], 'Revenue_Radio': [10, 20, 0,  30, 0, 50, 40, 0, 10], 'Revenue_Str': [0, 0, 10,0, 20, 50, 0, 30, 0]}    
df_result = pd.DataFrame(data_result)
```

With my code below, im gotting something wrong which is 2021-06 14 NY that should not exist in the final df

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, try:

```
output = df_1.merge(df_2, on=["date", "cod", "Zone"], how="outer")
output = output[output.set_index(["date", "cod"]).index.isin(df_1.set_index(["date", "cod"]).index)]
output = output.sort_values(['date','cod'], ignore_index=True)

      date cod   Zone  Revenue_Radio  Revenue_Str
0  2021-06  12     LA           10.0          0.0
1  2021-06  12     NY           20.0          0.0
2  2021-06  12  PARIS            0.0         10.0
3  2021-07  14     LA           30.0          0.0
4  2021-07  15     NY           50.0         50.0
5  2021-07  15  PARIS           40.0          0.0
6  2021-07  15     LA            0.0         30.0
7  2021-07  18  PARIS           10.0          0.0
```

Comment: than you but it is not really what i want i should not found the 2021-06  14     NY in my final df, either the 2021-08  18 NY because these rows exist in df_2 and not in def_1.

Comment: I'm confused. Do you want the rows that are only in df_1 or only in df_2?

Comment: initially in def_1 and if the cod and due_date exist in def_2 then should copy the data . Please have a look on my original post where i posted the expected data. Tell me if im not clear . thank you ^^

Comment: In your OP, the 2021-06 14 NY is in df_2 but here you say it shouldn't be in the output?

Comment: it is 2021-07 14 NY def_1 and 2021-06 14 NY not the same date @not_speshal you see what i mean?

Comment: Then why is 2021-07 14 LA and 2021-07 14 NY in your `df_result`? There is no 2021-07 14 in `df_2`

Comment: because it is in def_1 (third value in the first dataframe).

Comment: is it more clear @not_speshal.?

Comment: @dsp - See the edit. If that's not what you want, re-edit your question for clarity.

Comment: i will retry here, then modify my original post: if cod and date exist in def_2, then i want to copy the values of the columns in def_1. **2021-07 14 LA** exist in def_1 so i want to keep it.